# Qual componente posso usar como tabela no c#?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

[RESOLVIDO] Pego duas informações no banco de dados, tabela produtos: ID e nome.
Preciso mostrar para o usuário o ID e o nome de todos os produtos cadastrados..
O problema é que o listBox é apenas uma lista, ele não funciona igual uma tabela.
Alguém sabe se tem algum componente que posso colocar dados lado a lado? no c#

Comment: Já tentou GridView?

Comment: Tentei pesquisar sobre datagridview mas so encontrei sobre conectar banco de dados nele

Comment: COnsegui, resolvido

Comment: @ShariSharu, se alguma das respostas resolveu seu problema não se esqueça de marcar ela como respondida. Caso você tenha resolvido sozinho, adicione a resolução como resposta e marque ela como respondida, assim ajudará pessoas que tiverem a mesma duvida.

Answer (score 0):

Já que está buscando dados do banco de dados, você pode usar um elemento chamado `DataGridView`.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Para mais informações de como utilizar, segue alguns links:

- [Link 1](http://www.macoratti.net/08/08/c_pdgv1.htm)
- [Link 2](https://www.devmedia.com.br/c-datagridview-trabalhando-com-datagridview-no-microsoft-visual-studio/31137)

Comment: Mas dá pra usar o datagridview sem ter que linkar ele no banco de dados, pq tipo eu não me conecto com o banco de dados através do visualstudio, eu faço isso via código mesmo usando o driver do odbc, e já estou recuperando esses dados com uma pesquisa pronta, agora basta dispor visualmente esses dados rs, vou dar uma olhada

Comment: pelo que vi em seus links, só tem ensinando usar ele conectando direto no banco de dados, eu quero é passar um array pra ele

Comment: Valeu gente, consegui fazer

Answer (score 0):

Para tabela é o DataGridView, e se tiver um List do seu objeto, é só setar o datasource do dataGridView, exemplo:

```
datagridview1.datasource = lista
```

Ou então, se criar fazer manualmente, é necessário criar as colunas primeiro,
e depois fazer um foreach na sua lista e ir adicionando linha a linha;

Comment: mas esse datagridview da pra por os elementos que vem em um array? Ou é necessariamente importante linkar um banco de dados nele?

Comment: eu ja tenho os dados em um array, basta passar pro view, seja qual for

Comment: @ShariSharu na propriedade `DataSource` você pode jogar objetos com dados, não importa a origem, podem ser por exemplo um `Array`ou um `List`, que podem ter sido montados no código, lidos de um arquivo *xml*,ou vindos de um banco de dados

Comment: Sim, pode. E por exemplo se tiver 2 colunas no datagridview, o array voce vai ter posição 0 e posição 1, respectivamente quando fizer o datagridview.rows.add(array), ele vai assumir nas colunas os valores.

Comment: Valeu pessoal, deu certo :D